# Combinations of group items, no repeating

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, maxscript

I have items in 3 groups and I want to generate arrays like the following example:

```
Group 1 = {m1, m2, m3}
Group 2 = {m4, m5}
Group 3 = {m6, m7, m8, m9}

{m1, m4, m6}
{m2, m5, m7}
{m3, null, m8}
{null, null, m9}
```

Every element of the groups should only appear once in the generated arrays.
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: you might want to at least add a tag for the language you're talking about, so that experts in that language will help you

Comment: This doesn't make sense: sets don't have duplicate entries (or null entries). They are also unordered. But you can make a list of a set getting some order: `list({3,2,1}) == [1,2,3]`

Comment: It doesnt make sense because its pseudo code.
Im working in Maxscript, but I though I would post it as pseudo to get response from more people. You can threat the "Groups" just as arrays.

Comment: so you want to balance the sets? such that each one has size less than a given parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, its maxscript code which analyze multi-material that can have others multi-materials, and creates new materials from each ID. Maybe I was bit unclear in the first queastion sorry about that.

```
    local maxSubID = amax arrayNumSubs --it is the count of the array with highest number of items.


    for maxSubCounter = 1 to maxSubID do
    (
        tmpMat = multimaterial numsubs:mainMatIDs
        for subCounter = 1 to mainMatIDs do
        (
            if (rootMat[subCounter] != undefined) then
            (
                tmpMat[subCounter] = rootMat[subCounter][maxSubCounter]
            )else
            (
                tmpMat[subCounter] = undefined
            )
        )
        append materialsToApply tmpMat
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing something like this (keep in mind that this is pseudocode):

```
group1 = {m1, m2, m3}
group2 = {m4, m5}
group3 = {m6, m7, m8, m9}

len1 = group1.size
len2 = group2.size
len3 = group3.size

max = max(len1, len2, len3)

combination = {}
for i from 0 to max:

    combination = {}
    if(group1(i) exists)
        combination.add(group1(i))
    else combination.add("null")

    if(group2(i) exists)
        combination.add(group2(i))
    else combination.add("null")            

    if(group3(i) exists)
        combination.add(group3(i))
    else combination.add("null")            

    print combination
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser it certainly helped me :)